# Use glob node.js to know if a file exists in the parent folder using wildcard

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, glob

I need to search in the parent folder of where a node.js yeoman generator script is running to see if a file exists, but I won't know the file name - only the extension.

Glob:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

Folder Structure:

- C:\Work\
- C:\Work\Company\
- C:\Work\Company\Project\

Assume that the `Project` folder is where the command prompt is...  I want to run a Yeoman generator that looks into the `Company` folder first to see if a specific file exists.  It could be any file name, ending in `.sln`.

There are plenty of beginner resources, but I can't find any examples that show:

1. How to look in the parent folder successfully; and
2. How to work with the output (true/false?) to use in a variable for logic later in the function.

Here's what I tried to do, but I am admittedly much more adept in C# than I am in JS.

```
var globbed = glob("../*.sln", function(err, files){
    this.log(chalk.yellow("err = " + err));
    this.log(chalk.yellow("files = " + files));
});
```

and this...

```
var gOptions = { cwd: "../" };
var globbed = glob("*.sln", gOptions, function(err, files){
    this.log(chalk.yellow("err = " + err));
    this.log(chalk.yellow("files = " + files));
});
```

In both examples, `globbed` is an object, but I don't know what its properties are, and I am not able to access the internal function.

Essentially, I need to know if the file exists so that I can run an If/Then statement on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [glob.sync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob#globsyncpattern-options):

```
const files = glob.sync("*.sln", { cwd: "../" });
```

or simply

```
const files = glob.sync("../*.sln");
```

`files` will be an array of `*.sln` files, if any, in the parent directory.  Obviously, `glob.sync` is synchronous.

Comment: glob.sync() ... Duh!  Thanks!  :D

Comment: the second option (without cwd option) doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

glob(
 '*.sln',
 { cwd: path.resolve(process.cwd(), '..') },  // you want to search in parent directory
 (err, files) => {
   if (err) {
     throw err;
   }

   if (files.length) {
     // File exists. All matched filenames are inside files array.
   } else {
     // File does not exist. files array is empty.
   }
 }
);
```

`glob` is an asynchronous function so results are provided in a callback and not returned synchronously.

You can also test you glob expressions using [globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz)

Comment: So if I wanted to load the results of your example into a variable, what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: They are inside the `files` variable. It is just that this variable is accessible inside the callback function. If you do not want to use the callback function try to use `glob.sync()` as Mark suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used golb.Hope this will help you.

```
var fs=require('fs');
var pattern=RegExp('.md$');//Enter file extension here
fs.readdir('..//',(err,files)=>{
      //console.log(files);
      if(files.find((file)=>{return pattern.test(file)==true;})){
          //console.log('file found');  your code
        }
       else{
         //console.log('file not found'); your code
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is for a yeoman template generator, so console.log() is not an option.  :(

Comment: I have put console.log for testing purpose. You can edit that out. Also  I have edited my answer for that